# My first SFMC APP

Tags: marketing-cloud

I know this is not the right place for this kind of question but...
after writing my first Custom activity I have tried to write a simple search App for learning purposes.
I have tried to read the doc about how to create an app for SFMC (not the API- this is cool)
but all I get is how to connect the package.
all I find is docs for SFDC apps.

I can't even find answers to the simplest questions like how do I integrate HTML (yes canvas but how? with code? just append to HTML? is there a native command? if I want a new window? like in query SQL?), do I get a schema or any data from SFMC like in custom activated when the app connects as default or only if I make some API call?.
do I need to use Lightning Platform and Apax? can I use the SFCD tutorials (with the right changes of course)?

I have searched the internet for answers and haven't found anything.
do you know about a good reading material or know about a simple app in Github that I can read its code to see how it behaves?

sorry for the noob post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've explored custom applications for SFMC quite a bit and I 100% agree there's a huge disconnect between development of the app and what's outlined in the documentation.

First thing to note is that all AppExchange Apps and custom Applications are 100% externally hosted web applications. Once the app is developed, tested, etc, it's hosted on AWS, Heroku, or any other hosting platform.

How it is integrated in the AppExchange dropdown within SFMC is through the Installed Package (using the Marketing Cloud App option). What this will do is grab your public accessible endpoint and pull it into an iFrame.

There's really no limitation on what you can build and port into SFMC in this way, you don't need to use the lightning styles, and Apex is SFDC specific so  can't use that.

Regarding getting data for your application; from my understanding, any and all SFMC platform data you want to leverage in your application will need to be brought in through API calls. As far as I know, applications like Query Studio aren't limited to this as they are created by internal SF developers so they have access to things we don't have externally.

Comment: FWIW query studio uses the Public API to do everything it does